# Pass list(of string) values within parameter

Tags: .net, vb.net, arguments, generic-list

simple question: how to pass directly values within parameter of some function e.g:

```
MyFunction(byval myvariable as List(Of String))
...
```

now i want to pass something like (this not working):

```
MyFunction(New List(Of String) { "somevalue1", "somevalue2", "somevalue3" })
```

Answer (score 4):

In VB.NET you need to use `From` in [Collection-Initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617.aspx):

```
MyFunction(New List(Of String) From { "somevalue1", "somevalue2", "somevalue3" })
```

Comment: hmm this "From" is something new to me, can i use this way also when calling some class object i mean straightaway do New someclass(constructor) or its only for list.

Comment: @StackUser: that's called an Object-Initializer, you can read about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385125.aspx

Comment: ok but simple question call i for instance pass in parameter directly without declaring object class variable like this: New someclass("something") instead of Dim newcust as new someclass("Something") and then pass newcust. Similar way as it is in C# just straight away pass New...

Comment: What was your question?